# Mongoose findOne Returning all sub documents

Tags: mongoose, subdocument

I tried retrieving only one subdocument from the collection. But it is all subdocuments, even those which do not match the filter.

```js
LevelXP.findOne({
            'guild':"715192953118654467",
            'users.user': "687893451534106669"
        },(err,result)=>{
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log(result.users)
          }
})
```

[image: This is the data I have]

But when I use the above code it returns all subdocuments when I should return only 1.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use a position operator `$` ([reference link here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/)).
To make your query projection to just return sub-document which matches

So in your case, you can do this:

```
LevelXP.findOne({
            'guild':"715192953118654467",
            'users.user': "687893451534106669"
           },
           "users.$",
          (err,result)=>{
            console.log( result );
});
```

or, a variation of the syntax (`paired`), like this:

```
LevelXP.findOne({
            'guild':"715192953118654467",
            'users.user': "687893451534106669"
           },
           {"users.$":1},
           (err,result)=>{
            console.log( result );
});
```

Comment: Thanks it worked fine. But when I use .find instead of findOne it returns undefined. Do you know why?

Comment: @RohanKumar because find a cursor and findOne actually returns a fetched document. any reason why you need to use find?